# Default Rich Text Editor adding in <p> tags

Tags: ee3, richtext, rte

I dont know whether it is just down to the default RTE that EE give you but when add in a table, save and upload it hads in blank

at the end of the table and table heading. I have outlined the examples below:

Browser View:

[image]

EE Control Panel:

[image]

And then this is the code the browser outputs:

```
<div class="panel panel-sea teacherList">
  <div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title"> Class Team</h3>
   <p> </p>
  </div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><b>Mrs Harding</b></td>
    <td width="50%">Nursery Teacher and Key Worker</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Mrs Speakman</b></td>
    <td>Nursery Teacher and Key Worker </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Miss Ward</b></td>
    <td>Nursery Teaching Assistant </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Mrs Hubbard<br>
      </b></td>
    <td>Nursery Teaching Assistant </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I think it might just be because of the detault RTE but i just need some confirmation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well...a table is not really rich text. That's more something for a wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Thank you for answering, so is this just a RTE issue and would be solved with a WYSIWYG edit?

Comment: If you want to have editors inserting tables etc i would advise to use a wysiwyg editor such as wygwam yes.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. Thank you for the help :)